# How to serve static files with version number with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I just finished installing Nginx for wordpress but all static files with ?ver=x is redirecting to nginx's default page.

### Working

> /jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js

### Redirecting to default Nginx page

> /jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js?ver=1

Here is my configuration. What am I missing here?

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/domain.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
         }        
}
```

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: You should clear your browser cache.

Comment: Awesome. It's just that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below to the nginx should serve the file by taking just the filename and ignoring the version info.

```
 location ~ ^/(assets/js|assets/css) {
    root path/to/the/static/files;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    try_files $uri $1;
  }
```